# Diverging points in a plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a single variable function that possesses two diverging points. While the second one can be clearly seen in the plot the first one does not. How can I fix this?

[image]

Here is the expressions for $c(R)$.

```
c[R_]=-((148.044 Sqrt[
 0.25 + 4 R^2] (-0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) (0.5 + Sqrt[
   0.25 + 4 R^2]) (1. Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
   R^2 (4. Log[-0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]] - 
      4. Log[0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]])) (-0.000486111 - 
   0.000138889 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
   R^2 (-0.00212963 + 0.000925926 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) + 
   R^6 (-1.13611 + 0.0166667 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) + 
   R^4 (0.117824 + 0.123611 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) + 
   R^2 (R^4 (0.5 + 1. Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) Log[-0.5 + Sqrt[
         0.25 + 4 R^2]]^2 + 
      Log[-0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]] (-0.00111111 - 
         0.0111111 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
         R^2 (0.0444444 + 0.266667 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
            R^2 (1.49861 + 0.0666667 R^2 - 
               1.13611 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2])) + 
         R^4 (-1. - 2. Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) Log[
           0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]]) + 
      Log[0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]] (0.00111111 + 
         0.0111111 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
         R^2 (-0.0444444 - 0.266667 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
            R^2 (-1.49861 - 0.0666667 R^2 + 
               1.13611 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2])) + 
         R^4 (0.5 + 1. Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) Log[
           0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]]))))/(-0.003125 + 
 2.66815*10^-19 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
 R^2 (-0.0645833 - 0.00416667 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) + 
 R^4 (-0.0404514 + 0.0434028 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) + 
 R^8 (-34.2083 + 0.25 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) + 
 R^6 (3.90191 + 3.94271 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) + 
 R^8 (7.5 + 120. R^2 + 15. Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) Log[-0.5 + Sqrt[
    0.25 + 4 R^2]]^3 + 
 R^4 Log[-0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]]^2 (-0.283333 - 
    0.0333333 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
    R^2 (0.666667 + 1.33333 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
       R^2 (39.9792 + 75.9583 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
          R^2 (-136.833 + 1. Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]))) + 
    R^4 (-22.5 - 360. R^2 - 45. Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) Log[
      0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]]) + 
 Log[0.5 + Sqrt[
    0.25 + 4 R^2]] (2.03288*10^-19 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
    R^2 (0.00104167 - 2. R^8 + 0.114583 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
       R^4 (-2.49653 - 12.2847 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) + 
       R^2 (0.0430556 + 0.397222 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) + 
       R^6 (-61.7917 + 68.4167 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2])) + 
    R^4 Log[
      0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]] (-0.283333 - 
       0.0333333 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
       R^2 (0.666667 + 1.33333 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
          R^2 (39.9792 + 75.9583 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
             R^2 (-136.833 + 1. Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]))) + 
       R^4 (-7.5 - 120. R^2 - 15. Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) Log[
         0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]])) + 
 Log[-0.5 + Sqrt[
    0.25 + 4 R^2]] (-2.03288*10^-19 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
    R^2 (-0.00104167 + 2. R^8 - 0.114583 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
       R^6 (61.7917 - 68.4167 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) + 
       R^2 (-0.0430556 - 0.397222 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) + 
       R^4 (2.49653 + 12.2847 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2])) + 
    R^4 Log[0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]] (0.566667 + 
       0.0666667 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
       R^2 (-1.33333 - 2.66667 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
          R^2 (-79.9583 - 151.917 Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2] + 
             R^2 (273.667 - 2. Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]))) + 
       R^4 (22.5 + 360. R^2 + 45. Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]) Log[
         0.5 + Sqrt[0.25 + 4 R^2]]))))
```

To plot this expression I use

```
Plot[{c[R]}, {R, 0.001, 3}, Frame -> True,
  PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.38, 0.58, 0.01]}, Exclusions -> None]
```

This is the heat capacity of the system that I'm studying and the divergent points denote phase transitions, so I would like this to be seen explicitly in the figure.

Comment: Please include Mathematica code so that this plot can be replicated in our notebook sessions. Thanks.

Comment: `Exclusions -> All`.

Comment: @Syed $c(R)$ is terribly complicated. Is there a way to upload a minimal notebook?

Comment: You can use an online service such as Google drive. Get a public and accessible link by right-clicking on this file once it has been saved there. You can share such a link here.

Comment: @bloom The expression you posted does plot, but it does not give rise to the plot you showed. Can you check the expression?

Comment: @MarcoB i cannot post the full epxression, as code for some reason

Comment: Do not use machine precision for highly complicated expressions. `Rationalize` all of the values and `Simplify` the expression, i.e., c[ R_ ] = RHS // Rationalize[#, 0]& // Simplify;`

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you for your comment, but this does not work.